# Should we use native input event for custom form components in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Consider the following Vue.js code:

```
<template>

    <form @input="doSomethingOnInput">

        <!-- Native form control -->
        <input v-model="title" type="text" />

        <!-- VUE.JS COMPONENT -->
        <!-- Custom form control -->
        <date-picker v-model="expiryDate"></date-picker>

        <!-- VUE.JS COMPONENT -->
        <!-- Another custom form control -->
        <color-picker v-model="badgeColor"></color-picker>

    </form>

</template>
```

I have a form with three input elements. One is native input element whereas remaining two are custom input elements. Native `<input>` fires up `input` event which bubbles up the DOM tree.

For `<date-picker>` and `<color-picker>` native `input` events are not created. However, to support `v-model`, custom `input` event is anyways fired. Now, I know how to make native `input` event trigger from these custom elements.

**Question is - should I fire native input event from these custom input elements?** *Being an author of the reusable component library, my users might want to catch `input` event at the top i.e. at `<form>` element just as I shown.* **Does Vue.js recommend this? And will it cause any unforeseen issues?**

Comment: Could you also share the template of the components? From the documentation, seems like Vue.js encourages us to use v-model with custom inputs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: custom events don't bubble. If you need events to bubble, you'll either have to relay them "up the DOM" or use native event.